# Flutter's image_picker package: How to override the default bottom menu bar colors on review photo screen?

Tags: flutter, flutter-image-picker

I'm using Flutter imge_picker package, and it works well. But I'm unable to customize the bottom menu bar and text colors:
[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXfxE.png)

Is there a way to customize that bottom black background, "Retake" and "Use photo" colors?
The screenshot is made in light mode, so adding such a possibility will be a good option.

I'm using picker as in example, but there are no options for any UI customization.

```
ImagePicker()
        .pickImage(
            source: ImageSource.camera,
            preferredCameraDevice: CameraDevice.front)
        .then((image) {
debugPrint(image);
}
```

Can anybody suggest another package with such options if it's not customizable?